# Apply CIFilter on a region of interest

Tags: core-image, cifilter

Is it possible to apply a filter only on a region of interest or do I have to apply each filter on the whole image?

How to apply a filter on a defined region of interest? For example a selected rect/circle inside the input image?
How do I apply a filter on all pixel values deviate from a set RGB pixel by a fixed tolerance?